# Dealkalization of water

Tags: acid-base

I want to remove Alkalinity from tap water by using an acid. The starting point is about 370pm alkalinity, and I am wondering to reduce this to about 50ppm, could I use a weak acid like citric acid? Or do I need to use a strong acid, such as HCl?

Comment: *Why* do you want to do this?

Comment: ^ If what you want is to remove the calcium and other alkalines from your water, your best option may be reverse osmosis devices. Also common strong acids will not remove the alkalines, only make them more soluble.

Comment: It's for coffee and tea brewing, as too much alkalinity makes the brew taste flat. I can use Brita / BWT type filters to reduce calcium and alkalinity, but only to a certain extent. RO is a much larger investment, I would rather add a few drops of HCl to reduce the alkalinity to acceptable levels.

Comment: By the term "dealkalization" do you mean the removal of alkalinity ions or the adjustment of the pH value? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dealkalization_of_water

Answer (score 1):

Roughly speaking, any acid is equally effective if its pKa lies below the pH 7 you want for a neutral solution.  It does not have to be HCl at all, in fact citric acid works for all three of its commonly observed deprotonations (pKa = 6.4 for the third deprotonation and of course lower for the first two; [reference](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Citric_acid)).  So you may use citric acid assuming three equivalents per mole and you should get where you want to go.

As a matter of taste I prefer citrate in my tea versus chloride, anyway.

Comment: Thanks! I will give this a try and let you know the result. I don't have a pH kit but only a titration kit which tests alkalinity. However this should give me a reduced reading after adding the required amount citric acid? i.e. 1 mole citric acid to match 3 moles of hydrogencarbonate molecules?

Comment: That's what I would do, good luck!